# How to force measure name to display in the matrix?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

My matrix consists of one measure only. How would I go about forcing it's name to display on the table?

I am displaying calculated groups as columns.

[image: Matrix]

Answer (score 1):

You could right click your table and create a new column.

Dax code:

```
Col_Matrix_Title = "This is my Matrix row Title"
```

Then drag this new column on to the Rows field on the Matrix visual.

**UPDATE:**

To remove the Column header for the above row title you can do this:

Under Visual > specific column >
Set the text color to black for all Series.

- Turn on Apply to header
- Turn on apply to values

Under Visual > Column headers

- Set the text color to white

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you. Is there a way to remove the Column title from the header row? I'd like to keep the header row for my columns tho.

Comment: Yes. There is a title setting if you search. Please mark as answered to close the case.

Comment: I can find a setting to hide the visual title, but not the column title. Is this possible?

Comment: I updated the answer. Please mark it is closed if it works ok.